# Add formnovalidate tag to the submit_button in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use the rails function submit_button to generate a button for my form. How can I add the formnovalidate tag to this button?

The code in the view looks like

```
<%= f.submit_button('Draft Changes', class: 'btn btn-success') %>
```

Regards,
SB

Comment: My current code looks like - <%= f.submit_button('Draft Changes', class: 'btn btn-success') %>

Comment: Why would you want to do this on a button? Isn't this usually used for inputs? See e. g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065917/add-attribute-to-rails-helper-text-field (pretty much equivalent for your case, though)