# Add Attribute to Select Field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Slim Select for my select fields in my Rails 6 app. In order to allow users to select multiple options in the select, I have to [add the attribute `multiple` to my select tag.](http://slimselectjs.com/selects)

So it renders HTML, like: `<select id="foo" multiple>`.

How do I get `multiple` to show in the select tag?

I've read:

- [rails select tag with multiple values pre selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196382/rails-select-tag-with-multiple-values-pre-selected)
- [Add attribute to rails helper text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065917/add-attribute-to-rails-helper-text-field)
- [Ruby on Rails -- multiple selection in f.select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864513/ruby-on-rails-multiple-selection-in-f-select)

And I've tried:

```
<%= f.collection_select :foo, Tag.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: true, :html => 'multiple' %>

<%= f.collection_select :foo, Tag.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: true, input_html: { data: { multiple: "required"} } %>

<%= f.collection_select :foo, Tag.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: true, :html => {:multiple => true}  %>

<%= f.collection_select :foo, Tag.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: true, multiple: true %>

<%= f.collection_select :foo, Tag.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: true, :multiple => true %>
```

However, none of these add `multiple` in the select tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure :foo is an array that can save multiple ids, and put multiple: true as follow

```
<%= f.collection_select :foo, Tag.order(:name),:id,:name, {} , {multiple: true, class: '...'} %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! For some reason, after I changed it, the JS works correctly, but I can an error saying that it's unpermitted parameter? When I revert the code, it posts OK (the parameter's been whitelisted in the controller.

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out. Thanks for the array part in your answer, I was missing `: [ ]` in the allowed params.